# Solve for a range of values

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve the following eqn for Tco. The ultimate goal is to Plot Tco for zb values from 0 to 12.

```
hc = 6109.526
qNBzn=25605.9
Solve[446265 Sin[
    12/143 π (0.001958 + 
       zb)] == {(hc*(Tco - (569 + 
          4.87*^-9 (5.032*^9 - 5.03*^9 Cos[0.26 zb] + 
             2.60*^6 Sin[0.26 zb]))))*{1 + {((446265 Sin[
               12/143 π (0.001958 + zb)])/(hc*(Tco - (569 + 
                  4.87*^-9 (5.03*^9 - 5.03*^9 Cos[0.26 zb] + 
                    2.6*^6 Sin[0.26 zb])))))*(1 - 
            qNBzn/(446265 Sin[12/143 π (0.001958 + zb)]))}^2}^(1/
       2)}, Tco ]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should search around here ...

```
hc = 6109.526;
qNBzn=25605.9;
eq = {446265 Sin[12/143 π (0.001958 + zb)], 
       (hc*(Tco - (569 + 4.87*^-9 (5.032*^9 - 5.03*^9 Cos[0.26 zb] + 
        2.60*^6 Sin[0.26 zb]))))*(1 + (((446265 Sin[
          12/143 π (0.001958 + zb)])/(hc*(Tco - (569 + 
             4.87*^-9 (5.03*^9 - 5.03*^9 Cos[0.26 zb] + 
                2.6*^6 Sin[0.26 zb])))))*(1 - 
       qNBzn/(446265 Sin[12/143 π (0.001958 + zb)])))^2)^(1/2)}

Plot3D[eq, {Tco, 500, 700}, {zb, 0, 20 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}, PlotPoints -> 30]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Like this:

```
ListLinePlot[Tco /. FindRoot[(Equal @@ eq /. zb -> #), {Tco, 1}] & /@ 
              Range[0, 11.5, .5], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]